# Multiple day wise plots in timeseries dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

My data frame look like this -

```
In [1]: df.head()
Out[1]:
Datetime                     Value
2018-04-21 14:08:30.761     offline
2018-04-21 14:08:40.761     offline
2018-04-21 14:08:50.761     offline
2018-04-21 14:09:00.761     offline
2018-04-21 14:09:10.761     offline
```

I have data for 2 weeks. I want to plot Value against time (hours:minutes) for each day in week. If I am to see data one week at a time that also works.

I took a slice for a single day created a plot using plotly.

```
 In[9]: df['numval'] = df.Value.apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'online' else -1)
 In[10]: df.iplot()
```

If can have mutiple plots similar to this for sunday to saturday using few lines it would speed up my work
[image: Result]

Suggestions - 
Something like I can put in arguments as weekday (0-6), time (x axis) and Value (y axis) and it would create 7 plots.

```
In[11]: df['weekday'] = df.index.weekday
In[12]: df['weekdayname'] = df.index.weekday_name
In[13]: df['time'] = df.index.time
```

Any library would work as I just want to see the data and will need to test out modifications to data.

Optional - Distribution curve, similar to KDE, over data would be nice
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the exact answer you are looking for. Just giving an approach which could be helpful.

The approach here is to group the data based on date and then generate a plot for each group. For this you need to split the DateTime column into two columns - date and time. Code below will do that:

```
datetime_series = df['Datetime']
date_series = pd.Series()
time_series = pd.Series()

for datetime_string in datetime_series:
    date,time = datetime_string.split(" ")
    date_s = pd.Series(date,dtype=str)
    time_s = pd.Series(time, dtype=str)
    date_series=date_series.append(date_s, ignore_index=True)
    time_series = time_series.append(time_s, ignore_index=True)
```

Code above will give you two separate pandas series. One for date and the other one for time. Now you can add the two columns to your dataframe

```
df['date'] = date_series
df['time'] = time_series
```

Now you can use groupby functionality to group the data based on date and plot data for each group. Something like this:

First replace 'offline' with value 0:

```
df1 = df.replace(to_replace='offline',value=0)
```

Now group the data based on date and plot:

```
for title, group in df1.groupby('date'):
    group.plot(x='time', y='Value', title=title)
```